# How to check id String is Empty then put a define a default value if is Empty in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, is-empty, bearing

this is an taxi app where user get the rotation(bearing) of driver
is working well exept with devices that has not the rotaion (bearing)
like this
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhUdW.png)

if driver device doesn t have this feature then the users will get an error and the app crash

so my question is how to avoid this by check if Sting is Empty
and if is empty we have to put a default value on it

this it my code

```
if (icondriver.equals("2")) {
                   driverMarkers.add(
                           gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                   .position(currentDriverPos)
                                   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.carmap))
                                   .anchor((float) 0.5, (float) 0.5)
---------error line------------->>  .rotation(Float.parseFloat(driver.getBearing()))
                                   .flat(true)
                           )
```

this is how to get the String value

```
public String getBearing() {
       return bearing;
   }
```

this is the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujUeR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that if the String is empty, `0` is passed as default blank value. Also assumes the String will never be `null`.

```
(...)
rotation(Float.parseFloat(driver.getBearing().trim().isEmpty()?"0":driver.getBearing()))
(...)
```

`parseFloat` will automatically `trim()` the String. But in order to really check if `isEmpty` is not giving false negatives, trimming the String guarantees no String with just whitespaces is passed as valid. `String s = "    ";` will return `false` if called `isEmpty()` directly on it, without the `trim()` operation first.

So, the condition `driver.getBearing().trim().isEmpty()?"0":driver.getBearing()` is telling:

- If the String is empty, pass `"0"` (or your desired default value).
- If not, pass the String value as it is (`driver.getBearing()`).

Comment: @NewHere if you have some time, take a look at  saeedata's answer. If you have control of that part of the code, validating the string there will be much cleaner than the condition proposed in my answer. It's a better option if you have access to getBearing()

Comment: You could then call rotation(Float.parseFloat(driver.getBearing()) with no fear, as it is already validated (also null-checked)

Comment: Yes i did and it works too ( he forget  to put "{" after "   if(bearing == null || bearing.trim().isEmpty())" ) if some one want to try it

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getBearing() {

   String defaultValue = "0";
   String result;

   if(bearing == null || bearing.trim().isEmpty()) {
       result = defaultValue;
   } else {
       result = bearing;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: I do like this approach, but I assumed the questioner was not in control of this part of the code. May I propose an edit on it? also, +1

Comment: I know we were told more than a return is bad....but then you look at src from google, android, apache,.... every single one make it. So : https://i.ibb.co/vYdLTp0/wee.png

Comment: you're right dude, your answer is totally correct, but I guess if he can't modify this method he can declare a new method like getCorrectedBearing() in class and write condition there to prevent complexity and for S.O.L.I.D :)

Comment: with that you validate not only the non-null value, but also return the string trimmed. With this, OP won't need any further validation in its Float.ParseFloat method : ). I always prefer validating variables long before they must be used, that's why I prefer this approach.

Comment: +1 on the creation of a static String getCorrectedBearing() method in his class before calling the marker creation, if he doesn't have control of getBearing() directly

Comment: WORKS (forget to put "{" after " if(bearing == null || bearing.trim().isEmpty())" ) if some one want to try it)

Comment: I sincerely think this should be the accepted answer : ) @NewHere do not hesitate doing it. If in control of this method, better validate the string here (it will be much clearer for future maintenance, for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline if ->  bearing.isEmpty()?"0":bearing;